# Serve Image Data Via URL Through Proxy To In Memory Data

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, http, proxy

Goal: Render an image from raw data in IE11 and Edge.

Problem:

- The image is coming from a call to an API that only returns raw image data.
- The image data service is internal and cannot and should not be accessible directly from external networks (the internet).
- The data can be rendered in other browsers using a base64 encoding of the image sent into an image tag, `<img src="data://image/jpeg;base64,#{base64encodedDataHere}">`, but it will not render in IE as the data will always exceed the 32kb limit for this type of tag.

Question:
In my Rails app, would it be possible to set up some kind of proxying such that I could build a URL to my Rails app server and use it in an image tag, such as `<img src='http://my-rails-app-server.com/images/123'>`, that would then hit the service to retrieve the image data and then return it to the browser in some way that it would expect for an image source.

Some pseudo code:

```
class ImageProxy < ApplicationController
  def show
    data = ExternalImageDataRetriever.get_data_from("internal-network-image-service/images/123")
    render something: data
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was exceptionally easy.

I already had built the tool that makes the request to the external API inside my network for the image. Calling the API returns 2 important things: the raw image data and the mime type.

All I had to do was pass these through rails.

The controller action ended up looking like this

```
class ImageProxy < ApplicationController
  def show
    service_response = ExternalImageDataRetriever.get_data_from("internal-network-image-service/images/123")
    render text: service_response.data, layout: nil, content_type: service_response.mime_type
  end
end
```

After that it was just using the route to that controller action in an image tag in the view.

```
<%= image_tag image_proxy_path(id: 123) %>
```